# Converting Epoch time with timezone to Excel format time?

Tags: c++, excel, datetime, epoch

I need to be able to convert Epoch time to Excel time.
Why Excel, because working with the numeric excel time is faster that any parsing done on display formats.

Current time of `2018-06-08 12:46:58 CDT`with UTC 1528480019 should give **0.5326157**.
But converted to the New_York time or `2018-06-08 13:46:58 EDT` will give **0.574282367**.
I only need to convert the time field to Excel style.

Here is my incomplete code:

```
double GetTime(Datetime currtime, std::string tz = "TZ=America/New_York")
{
  std::time_t t = currtime;
  //tzset(tz);
  std::tm tm = *std::localtime(&t);
  return ((tm.tm_hour * 3600 + (tm.tm_min) * 60.0 + tm.tm_sec) / 86400.0);
}
```

The code works, but only for local time which is "America/Chicago".
I have been unable to use the set the timezone to the one I might need.
Also tm seems to be limited to seconds, but I need to handle milliseconds and microseconds as well.

Furthermore, I need it to be fast and the the current implementation parses the time into separate fields and then I combine it into what I need which seems to do a lot of extra work.

Comment: [You're playing in a minefield.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214326/excel-incorrectly-assumes-that-the-year-1900-is-a-leap-year) Good luck!

Comment: I don't care about the date, ONLY the time. Can you tell me of a faster way to represent 24 hour time?

Comment: The question states, "I need to be able to convert Epoch time to Excel time." Check out [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) then ask about X instead of Y.

Comment: P.S. I'm not trying to be a dick. I'm just trying to help, and the first step is understanding *what* you're actually trying to do and *why* you believe this is a solution you should pursue

Answer (score 0):

This problem can easily be solved with [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source date/time/timezone library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html), which is very efficient.  This library is also in the current C++20 working draft, under `namespace std::chrono`.  So in the future, porting your code to just use the std::lib ought to be as easy as changing a few namespaces.

```
double
GetTime(std::chrono::system_clock::time_point currtime,
        date::time_zone const* tz = date::current_zone())
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    zoned_time<system_clock::duration> zt{tz, currtime};
    auto lt = zt.get_local_time();
    auto ld = floor<days>(lt);
    using ExcelTime = duration<double, days::period>;
    ExcelTime tod = lt - ld;
    return tod.count();
}
```

Instead of taking a `Datetime` it takes a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`, and instead of a `std::string`, a `date::time_zone const*`.

On the three big platforms (llvm/gcc/MSVS), the coarsest `system_clock::time_point` is microseconds, which meets your precision goals.

Step one is to create a `zoned_time` which is a pairing of a `time_point` with a `time_zone`.  From this one can get a `local_time`.

`floor<days>` truncates the precision of a `time_point` to `days`.  If one subtracts the day-precision `time_point` from the finer-precision `time_point`, one gets the local time-of-day.

If you store this local time-of-day in a `chrono::duration` that has a `double` as its representation, and a period of 1 day, then you get the Excel Time-Of-Day format.

This can be used like:

```
int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(9);
    std::cout << GetTime(sys_seconds{1528480019s}, locate_zone("America/Chicago")) << '\n';
    zoned_time<system_clock::duration> zt{"America/New_York",
                                          local_days{2018_y/6/8} + 13h + 46min + 58s};
    std::cout << GetTime(zt.get_sys_time(), zt.get_time_zone()) << '\n';
}
```

which outputs:

```
0.532627315
0.574282407
```

Above, I struggled to come as close as possible to your existing API.  However if you adopt this library, you can make it even simpler, and slightly more efficient, by adopting a "more native" API:

```
std::chrono::duration<double, date::days::period>
GetTime(const date::zoned_time<std::chrono::system_clock::duration>& zt)
{
    using namespace date;
    auto lt = zt.get_local_time();
    return lt - floor<days>(lt);
}
```

Now `GetTime` takes just a single parameter of type `zoned_time<system_clock::duration>`, and returns a `duration<double, days::period>`.  All that's left for `GetTime` to do is truncate the local time to days-precision and subtract to get time-of-day.

The demo in `main` is also simplified:

```
std::cout << GetTime({"America/Chicago", sys_seconds{1528480019s}}).count() << '\n';
std::cout << GetTime({"America/New_York",
                      local_days{2018_y/6/8} + 13h + 46min + 58s}).count() << '\n';
```

And gives the same output as before.